# IOS build errors - Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode

Below are errors while building in latest xcode 13 & Mac Apple Pro M1 chip

```
<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xx-cwbykxafbbbrfjbaeyuaxhdrivdp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Stripe/Stripe.modulemap' not found


<unknown>:0: error: module map file '/Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xx-cwbykxafbbbrfjbaeyuaxhdrivdp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/YogaKit/YogaKit.modulemap' not found
Command PrecompileSwiftBridgingHeader emitted errors but did not return a nonzero exit code to indicate failure
```

Most of the answers mentioned to edit pod file & write exclude configuration hence the tried below fix -

```
  installer.aggregate_targets.each do |aggregate_target| 
      aggregate_target.user_project.native_targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
          config.build_settings['LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS'] = ['$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift', '$(inherited)'] # or it won't build on apple silicon
          # without explicitly clearing this out, it flaps between excluding arm64 or not
          
          # Fix some library / linker errors
          config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'YES' # only one at a time
          config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS'] = 'arm64 x86_64' # you need both to work on both CPU archs / release etc
          config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        end
      end
      aggregate_target.user_project.save
    end

    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|

        # We support a smaller range of deployment than some libraries, eliminate related noise
        # This also avoids a nasty Folly bug about an API not available until ios10+
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
      end
    end
```

Also couple of answers mentioned to open workspace file which also tried but these errors are not resolving. Requesting if someone can provide right pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue with Xcode 14 in M1 Mac running macOS Ventura. The following workaround fixed the issue for me.

- Right click on **Applications -> Xcode**
- Choose **Get Info**
- Select **Open with Rosetta** option if it's not selected

[image]